# Can we save data to relationship in neo4j with Spring?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, neo4j, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-neo4j

when using Cypher command, I can easily save data to relationship, but in Spring D, I don't know how to save and get data from relationship between two node.
This is my example:

Class User

```
@NodeEntity
public class User {
    private String username;
    private String saltedPassword;
    private String lastIp;
    private boolean enabled;
    private Profile profile;

    @Relationship(type = "FOLLOWS")
    private Set<User> followings;
    @Relationship(type = "FOLLOWED_BY")
    private Set<User> followers;
    @Relationship(type = "HAS_POST")
    private Set<Post> posts;
    @Relationship(type = "HAS_COMMENT")
    private Set<Comment> comments;
    @Relationship(type = "HAS_VERITFICATION_TOKEN")
    private Set<VerificationToken> verificationTokens;
}
```

Class VertificationToken

```
@NodeEntity
public class VerificationToken {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(UUIDStringGenerator.class)
    private String id;
    private String token;
    private long expiryDate;

    @Relationship(type = "BELONG_USER")
    private User user;
}
```

This relationship between two node is HAS_VERIFICATION_TOKEN. As it is now. I can only save a Set in User, but if I need add data to this relationship, I can't.

Could somebody help me? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using Spring Data Neo4j 5 (which is **not** the latest major version by the way), you can introduce a `@RelationshipEntity` class, to model the relationship between your `User` and `VerificationToken` entities:

```java
@RelationshipEntity("HAS_VERIFICATION_TOKEN")
public class VerificationTokenOwnership {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    // add your extra properties here

    @StartNode
    private User user;

    @EndNode
    private VerificationToken token;

    // getters and setters

}
```

Your `User` field can then become:

```java
    @Relationship(type = "HAS_VERIFICATION_TOKEN")
    private Set<VerificationTokenOwnership> verificationTokens;
```

Note: it seems a bit strange to have both `HAS_VERIFICATION_TOKEN` and `BELONG_USER` relationships, you should ideally have only one of these.

Comment: I tried and received result as below image. This isn't a completely expected result with me. Following your hint, relationship create a node, but I want relationship is only a edge and save data to this edge. Could you give me other solution? Thank you!
https://i.stack.imgur.com/9lJMi.png

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following: what is the issue exactly?

Comment: well, my problem is how to save data to relationship as edge between two node, but not relationship as node.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/whWiJ.png

Comment: `VerificationTokenOwnership` is persisted as a relationship (since it's annotated with `@RelationshipEntity`), not as a node.